# SUM MULTIPLE TIMES HH:MM SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to add multiple times in the format(hh:mm). I need to write a function/stored procedure which can accepts multiple parameters as input and return sum time.

```
function addTimes(<input1>,<input2>...) //input can be multiple 2,3,4,5..
{
  input1 = 01:00
  input2 = 02:00
  input3 = 03:00
  return 06:00
}
```

I have to call above addTimes functions in anyway which i mentioned like below from another stored procedure.

```
dbo.addTimes(01:00) //return 01:00
dbo.addTimes(01:00,02:00) //return 03:00
dbo.addTimes(01:00,02:00,03:00) //return 06:00
```

Please help and throw some ideas to me. SQL SERVER.

Comment: I feel i can use default for optional parameters and convert all hh:mm into minutes inside function and convert to hh:mm back again inside function and return. Is it the right approach or anyother elegant approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ReturnTime] (
   @InputString VARCHAR(8000)     
)

RETURNS @Items1 TABLE (
      Item time
)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Items TABLE(Item VARCHAR(8000))
declare @Delimiter VARCHAR(50)=','

      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

      DECLARE @Item time
      DECLARE @ItemList VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            -- Set @ItemList = @ItemList minus one less item
            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      INSERT INTO @Items1
      SELECT Cast (DateAdd (S, Sum (DATEDIFF (S, '00:00:00', item)), '00:00:00') as Time) FROM @Items

      RETURN

END -- End Function
```

### Query

```
select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, item,108),1,5) from dbo.ReturnTime('01:00') --//return 01:00
select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, item,108),1,5) from dbo.ReturnTime('01:00,02:00')-- //return 03:00
select SUBSTRING(convert(varchar, item,108),1,5) from dbo.ReturnTime('01:00,02:00,03:00') --//return 06:00
```

Comment: @srinath- Thank you so much but i need return result like hh:mm '01:00' but i m getting 01:00:00.0000000.

Comment: @srinath- if i add many times, i m not getting desired outcome.

Comment: 00:00 
00:00 
00:00
07:40
08:13
08:05
06:53
00:00 .if i add this i get 06:41 kind of. I need sum of all time

Comment: im getting required result after little modification. RETURNS @Items1 TABLE (
      Item varchar(8000)
)    ---  SELECT CAST(i.time_sum/3600 AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'+ CAST(i.time_sum%3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)) FROM ( SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(S, '00:00:00', item)) AS time_sum FROM @Items) i

Answer (score 1):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[addTimes] (
       @TimeSerial VARCHAR(8000)     
    )

    RETURNS varchar(100)


    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @xml XML
        SET @xml='<n>'+REPLACE(@TimeSerial,',','</n><n>')+'</n>'
        DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)
        SELECT @s=CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MINUTE, SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,s.b.value('.','time'))),0),108) FROM @xml.nodes('n') s(b)
        RETURN @s

    END -- End Function

    SELECT dbo.[addTimes]('01:00,02:00,03:00,,09:00')
```

--15:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like following

```
Declare @tbl table(tm time)
insert into @tbl values('0:10')
insert into @tbl values('3:20')
insert into @tbl values('1:00')

declare @query varchar(max)
set @query= (Select  Stuff(
        (
        Select '+CAST(''' + LEFT(CAST(tm as varchar(50)),5) +''' AS DATETIME)'
        From @tbl
        For Xml Path('')
  ), 1, 1, ''))

SET @query ='SELECT LEFT(CAST('+@query +' As Time),5)'

exec(@query)
```